# Error while creating dynamic sql to rpelace db prefix but getting error error msg

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem converting strings (in 12\11\2013 format) to Datetime (in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format) in dynamic sql.

You can see the related example and result in the below:
   declare @dbPrefix varchar(2),
     @cob varchar(20) ,
     @Sql  varchar(200)
     declare @m_cobMinusOne datetime,

```
 @m_cobEOM varchar(20),
 @m_cobEOY varchar(20),
 @m_cobFUN varchar(20)
 set @cob = '12/11/2013' 
set @dbPrefix='q_'
set @m_cobMinusOne =  convert(varchar(20),@m_cobMinusOne,103)
set @m_cobEOM =  convert(varchar(20),@m_cobMinusOne,103)

exec(N'select ' + @m_cobMinusOne + '= bdh_prev_bus_d ,' + @m_cobEOM + '= bdh_prev_mo_end_d 
from ' +@dbPrefix+'dbbdm005..bdh_bus_date_ref  where bdh_bus_d = ''' + @cob + '''')
```

Comment: "set m_cobMinusOne =  convert(varchar(20),m_cobMinusOne,103)" ?? m_cobMinusOne is a datetime, why set a varchar to a datetime?

Comment: Tip change exec('...') to print ('...') have a look what it would be trying to do.@m_cobMinusOne will always be null as well, was it meant to convert @cob?

Comment: yeah you are right,, its not showing any result and taking Null value

Comment: Please repsond, how to use same concept for insert in to select *

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here you could do something like this ....

```
declare 
  @dbPrefix      varchar(2),
  @cob           varchar(20) ,
  @m_cobMinusOne datetime, 
  @m_cobEOM      varchar(20),
  @SqlQuery      NVARCHAR(MAX);

set @cob           = '20131211'; 
set @dbPrefix      = 'q_';
set @m_cobMinusOne =  convert(varchar(20),@m_cobMinusOne,103);
set @m_cobEOM      =  convert(varchar(20),@m_cobMinusOne,103);

SET @SqlQuery =  N'select   @m_cobMinusOne = bdh_prev_bus_d ,  @m_cobEOM = bdh_prev_mo_end_d ' +
                 N'from ' + QUOTENAME(@dbPrefix+'dbbdm005') +'..bdh_bus_date_ref  ' +
                 N'where bdh_bus_d = @cob';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlQuery                
                     ,N'@m_cobMinusOne VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT, @m_cobEOM VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT, @cob VARCHAR(20)'
                     ,@m_cobMinusOne OUTPUT
                     ,@m_cobEOM      OUTPUT
                     ,@cob
```

Comment: Hi Ali,In table, values of bdh_prev_bus_d is in date time format like '2013-12-11' will it make any issue?

Comment: If it's a datetime column then you should use datetime variable, once you have got the value in a datetime variable then format it in any way you like, but you can't assign a value to a varchar variable returned from a datetime column

Comment: Ok, How can i check if its returning correct values?

Comment: Hi Ali,Thanks,I ran the query after changing it to datetime for all @cob.@cobminusone and it ran fine.But how can i check if its returning correct values

Comment: How can i use this db prefix in inster query ,?